# Is it safe to use the results of map subscription operator, without previous initialization?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have code for counting words:

```
std::map<std::string,int> counts;
std::string word;

while(cin>>word) 
{ 
   counts[word]+=1; //????
}
```

Is it safe? AFAIK, counts[word] for previously unseen key, will create "value-initialised" value. "value-initialised" is "zero-initialised" for POD types. Hence, looks like it is safe.

But, there is information about bugs in Visual Studio in implementation of value-initialization for some situations (I don't understand the details).

So, my question is: Is it safe to use code like mine, if I want to use it both with g++ and Visual C++?

Comment: Do you have links to those bugs? Otherwise it's perfectly safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard's description of the `operator []` of class `std::map`

> Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts
>   value_type(x, T()) into the map.

So this statement

```
counts[word]+=1;
```

Thus the value of `counts[word]` will be initially equal to 0.

If you mean some bug of MS the VC++ then you should give a reference to the description of the bug in the microsoft site. I do not know such a bug of MS VC++. It would be a very serious bug and I doubt that it exists.

So it is safe to use with any compiler. Such kinds of bugs do not live long.:)

Comment: He already knows that this is safe according to the standard, he asks about potential bugs in the implementation of gcc and MSVC.

Comment: @ Baum mit Augen His question "So, my question is: Is it safe to use code like mine"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The full question is: "Is it safe to use code like this with MSVC and gcc, even with the buggy implementation of value initialization the former uses?".

Comment: @Baum mit Augen  And what?! Where is a reference to this bug if it is exists?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow So because there is not enough information in the question itself you post a not-an-answer instead of asking for clarification in a comment?